# Nginx + PHP-FPM + APC slow response times

Tags: performance, ubuntu, nginx, apc, php

We currently have a Nginx server setup with PHP-FPM and APC for caching. It was setup to run one medium load website, where we wanted to put an emphasis on site load times as their whole business relies heavily on the website (online bookings).

The specs are:
1 CPU,
1GB Ram,
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
Nginx 1.1.19,
PHP-FPM 5.3.10

It has been working without any issues for quite awhile now (approx 1 year).

However we needed to setup a split testing situation to test a new version of the website. As we weren't able to just alternate between different code snippets (using a CMS and the database structure had also changes) we decided we would use a subdomain and send 20% of traffic to the subdomain instead.

To achieve this we simply created a new server block and setup the new site completely standalone in a new folder. Then inside the original server block file we used nginx split clients to set a cookie and redirect to 'new' if in that percentile.

We figured it was fine to just do this on the main/old site as all of their traffic comes from Google and is unlikely to be a repeat client in the testing period so the likelyhood of someone coming direct to 'new' is very low and wouldn't impact on the results

It was working fine at first be after a few days we started to get some complaints regarding slow load times. After some debugging it was only traffic heading to 'new' and is only intermittent. The original site isn't being effected at all at this point.

We have slowly disabled features trying to workout where the problem is but we can't find where the issue lies. The split testing has been disabled temporarily and it turns out that even if you try to load the subdomain directly, it will sometimes have a very slow initial response (around 20s).

At first I thought this might be a caching issue so we disabled APC completely but it hasn't resolved the problem. We did have fastcgi cache enabled at one point to try speed it up but this was disabled long ago.

We have a few other servers with very similar setups so I am struggling to find where the issue lays.

Here are file snippets

**Nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        use epoll;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
        send_timeout 60;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        #fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=100m inactive=60m;
        #fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;

        open_file_cache          max=2000  inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid    30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors   off;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Site 1 / Original**

```
split_clients "app${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}${date_gmt}" $upstream_variant {
        20% "new";
        * "original";
}

map $cookie_split_test_version $upstream_group {
        default    $upstream_variant;
        "new"      "new";
        "original" "original";
}

geo $internal_request {
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1;
        default 0;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com otherdomain.com$
        return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        add_header Set-Cookie "split_test_version=$upstream_group;Path=/;Max-Age=3600;";

        if ($upstream_group = "new") {
              set $test_group 1;
        }
        if ($test_group = 1) {
                return 301 $scheme://new.domain.com$request_uri;
                break;
        }


        ssl_certificate path/to/ssl;
        ssl_certificate_key path/to/sslkey;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;


        root /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.domain.com

    client_max_body_size 2M;


        location / {
                try_files $uri @website;
        }


    location @website {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/framework/main.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /framework/main.php;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri&$args;

                fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT production;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        }

    ///other location directives

    expires 2w;
}
```

**Site 2 / New**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/new;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name new.domain.com

        ssl_certificate path/to/ssl;
        ssl_certificate_key path/to/sslkey;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;

        client_max_body_size 2M;


        location / {
                try_files $uri @website;
        }


    location @website {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/framework/main.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /framework/main.php;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri&$args;

                fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT new;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        }

    ///other location directives

    expires 2w;
}
```

**Bits from PHP-FPM pool.d**

```
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

I also don't think its a memory issue (not getting any memory alerts)

```
top - 10:24:51 up 54 days, 11:11,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.12, 0.12
Tasks:  77 total,   1 running,  76 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  6.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 91.6%id,  1.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1015380k total,   896120k used,   119260k free,   149888k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   333820k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28873 www-data  20   0  293m  47m 5572 S  6.0  4.8   0:41.26 php5-fpm
25241 www-data  20   0 80176 6112 2036 S  0.3  0.6  28:57.78 nginx
28872 www-data  20   0  293m  47m 5548 S  0.0  4.8   0:34.50 php5-fpm
28874 www-data  20   0  290m  44m 5556 S  0.0  4.5   0:34.60 php5-fpm
28875 www-data  20   0  286m  39m 5320 S  0.0  4.0   0:40.08 php5-fpm
29249 www-data  20   0  281m  34m 5288 S  0.0  3.5   0:32.04 php5-fpm
31620 www-data  20   0  280m  33m 5176 S  0.0  3.4   0:02.06 php5-fpm
```

The log files don't seem to provide me with any useful information and it isn't causing anything to log in php slowlog with 15s threshold.

As mentioned this is only an intermittent problem and I can't find a pattern to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also if there is a better way of doing the split testing I would love to hear about it.

Comment: could it be ssl related? do you have a separate ssl key for subdomain or using a wildcard cert? also check dns lookup on the machine itself - just to rule that out. turn on nginx and php-fpm debug logs - see which is using up the majority of time. if is in php, check for db query times etc. ah, just saw that php-fpm slowlog is empty, so I'd suspect non php-fpm issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you NewRelic (or any other profiling tool) installed? That will help figuring out the exact reason for slow transactions as the problem may entirely be somewhere else.

Comment: We have the basic version of NewRelic installed but so far I haven't been able to debug this problem with it. As both sites use the same CMS, there is only one file that gets used for the whole site and the filename that NewRelic is referencing is the same for both